# Reading serial data from arduino -- invalid syntax error

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to write a python script to read values from the arduino's serial port and write it to a file so I can log the data.

The arduino code is long and complicated, but I'm using Serial.println() to print an integer to the serial port (located at /dev/ttyACM0)

```
import sys
import serial
import getpass
import datetime
import instrumentDriver

"""location of the arduino"""
location = '/dev/ttyACM0'

"""Connect to the arduino"""
arduino = instrumentDriver.serialDevice(location)

"""Successfully connected!"""
filename = str(sys.argv[1])
dataFile = open(filename+'.dat','w')

"""The main loop -- data is taken here and written to file"""
while True:
    try:
        datum = arduino.read()
        print datum
        dataFile.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        dataFile.write('\t')
        dataFile.write(datum)
        dataFile.write('\n')
    except:
        dataFile.close()
        break
```

The instrumentDriver.py is just a wrapper for pySerial:

```
class serialDevice:
    def __init__(self,location):
        self.device = location
        self.port = serial.Serial(location,9600)

    def write(self,command):
        self.port.write(command)

    def read(self):
        return self.port.readline()
```

I've used this block of code years ago and it worked fine, but it seems to be failing right now and I'm not entirely sure why.  I get a SyntaxError on line 45:

```
scottnla@computer-1 ~/Documents/sensorTest $ python readSerial.py file
  File "readSerial.py", line 45
    print datum
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried changing the print statement, but no matter what I'm printing, I get a syntax error -- I speculate that the problem may actually be with the arduino.read() line.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using phyton 2 or 3? Try to force your choise. Also what error and where?

Comment: Is that your *exact* code? There are indentation problems in the block following the """write it to file, along with a timestamp""" docstring (also -- why are you using docstrings as regular comments? See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments for PEP8 information on this)

Comment: Whoops, what an embarrassing mistake!  Included the error.  I'm using python 2.7.3

Comment: The indentation errors were a formatting error; i've fixed them now.

Comment: Do you get a syntax error if you comment out the print line?

Comment: If I comment it out, the program runs and ends immediately with an empty file generated.  If I change the print statement to something like "print 'hello, world'", then it fails in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There is still an indentation issue; rewritten as below, it should run:

```
import sys
import datetime

class serialDevice:
       def __init__(self,location):
              self.device = location
              self.port = sys.stdin # changed to run on terminal

       def write(self,command):
              self.port.write(command)

       def read(self):
              return self.port.readline()

"""location of the arduino"""
location = '/dev/ttyACM0'

"""Connect to the arduino"""
arduino = serialDevice(location)

"""Successfully connected!"""
filename = str(sys.argv[1])
dataFile = open(filename+'.dat','w')

"""The main loop -- data is taken here and written to file"""
while True:
    try:
        """retrieve the raw analog number from the arduino's ADC"""
        datum = arduino.read()
        """write it to file, along with a timestamp"""
        print datum
        dataFile.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        dataFile.write('\t')
        dataFile.write(datum)
        dataFile.write('\n')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        """this allows for the user to CTRL-C out of the loop, and closes/saves the file we're writing to."""
        dataFile.close()
        break
```

Comment: What did you change?  I don't see any obvious differences.

Comment: Aligning under **"""write...** basically

Comment: ah.  that's not the problem -- for some reason it isn't displaying right, but the indentation is aligned as it should be.

Comment: ok. Could you provide the actual code because line 45 doesn't exist in the sample provided. Also are you sure it's python 2.7 (print syntax changed in python3)? Does it work without the print statement? You could also try sys.stdout.write(str(datum)+"\n").

Comment: I eliminated comments that were defunct code, which is where the difference in line numbers come from.

I'm reformatted the initial post to have proper indentation.

When I type "python" into my command line, it says version 2.7.3

Comment: Did you try to remove the print statement?

Comment: If I comment it out, the program runs and ends immediately with an empty file generated. If I change the print statement to something like "print 'hello, world'", then it fails in the same way.

Comment: You should try to remove the try: ... except to see the actual error which may be hidden (without the print). It would be better to catch the keyboard only with KeyboardInterrupt as in the  modified code